# how do i re-align text to its border at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, text, border

how do i move header text ("bottom text") so that it sits just above the border at the bottom of the page?
i've tried changing styles and classes in the ,  and  tags and nothing has worked?
code below (partial, relevant only code due to overly strict posting guidelines.).

```
<footer>
<style>

h3 {position:fixed; solid white;
width:100%;
border-bottom:4px solid white; text-align:center;
}

.bottom-text {position:absolute; solid white; width:100%; text-align- 
center; color:white;
}

</style>

<h3 class="bottom-text" style="border-bottom:5px; border-bottom- 
style:solid; border-bottom-color:white; padding-bottom:17em; color:white; 
font-family:arial;">bottom page</h3>


</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduciable code snippet. The source of images might change and then this question would be worthless. Also it can be considered bad manners if you ask us to help you and letting us type the code from a picture while you could simply copy & paste it.

Comment: also what have you tried so far? what isnt working for you? Then plenty emthods as using `position: fixed/absolute;` being one of the most simple tasks.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
background:#000;
}

footer{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #fff;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
border:2px solid #fff;
}


.bottom-text{
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<p class="bottom-text">Bottom text</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: i used this and it shifted the text and border to the left, keeping their respective top and bottom postions? adding a text align center tag did nothing

Comment: @kyre white check the answer i edited my answer.

Comment: do i keep the existing tags or change to <div> and <p> ?  and how do i keep it as my original border (in picture in original question)

Comment: @kyre white check the answer i edited my answer again.

Comment: you can replace p tag with you h3 tag